# How can i convert a comma seperated string to json object type using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

As a beginner in angular js, I am struck to convert the comma separated string from MySQL db to json object of bellow type
input :

```
excellent,very_good,good,poor
```

output:

```
 Object {excellent: "excellent", very_good: "very_good", good: "good",poor: "poor" }
```

I tried with

```js
 var data='excellent,very_good,good,poor';
 if(data!=null){
    data= data.split(',').reduce((res,x)=>{
      res[x] = x;
      return res
    },{});
}
console.log(data);
```

It works but the problem is it doesn't support in Safari.

Comment: are you seeing any error in safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code, that should do the job:

```js
var data = 'excellent,very_good,good,poor';
var item = '';
var result = {};

if(data !== null) {
  data = data.split(',');
  
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    item = data[i].trim();
    
    result[item] = item;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to compatibility issue of **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** so use simple [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) instead

```js
var data = 'excellent,very_good,good,poor';

var strArr = data != null ? data.split(',') : [],
  res = {};

for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++)
  res[strArr[i]] = strArr[i];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 3) + '</pre>');
```

---

Or check [reduce polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill) option for old browser.

Comment: @VishnuSBabu :   glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
  var data = 'excellent,very_good,good,poor';
  var jsonfied = {
    dataObj: data.replace(/,$/, "").split(",").map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name
      };
    })
  };
  $scope.master = jsonfied;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
    Maser :- {{master}}
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well do it

```
var data = "excellent,very_good,good,poor".split(','),
    res = {};
angular.forEach(data, function(value, key){
   res[value] = value;
});
console.log(res);
```

I hope to be of assistance.